# I had to squash git commit before merge. However, it was merged to master branch, How can I cancel merge, squash them and merge again?

Tags: git, github

On the remote repository, I mistakenly merged my test commits. It should be squashed before merge. Can I cancel merge, squash them and merge again?

Comment: Did you actually finish the merge? Did you use a pull request? Are you collaborating with others?

Comment: Yes, I already merged with pull request. This is a remote repo with others..

Comment: Well, you really can't rewrite history then, and if your commits are okay, even if you didn't squash, there's no good reason to rewrite it

Comment: Really it's not your fault. The repo should have been configured to force you to squash and merge if that's the policy

Comment: hmm. I see, on github, I clicked "squash and merge", and it worked last time when I did. However, this time, it did not squash it... anyway thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

type `git reflog`
Check the headNumber after which you have squash and merged your repo.
Revert back to that position using the command:- `git reset --soft HEAD~headNumber`